# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'da'

Tags: python

I am calling another program(script2.py) from the script1.py. The script1.py contains a button when i press it, it will start to execute the script2.py. I want to use a variable of script1 in script2. I have tried 2 way to fetch it but giving the error or the empty list. Please help me with this and let me know if any other information is needed. Thank you.

```
script1.py 

class window2:  #i have tried to use d but even the value changes in the __init__function it is giving me a empty list in script2 print function
    d=[]
    def __init__(data):
        self.data=data
        window2.d=data
        data_copy()


def data_copy(): #so created this function to fetch da but giving the following error
    da=window2.d


script2.py

from script1 import data_copy
from script1 import window2

def view():
    print(window2.d) #giving empty list
    print(data_copy().da) #giving error
```

Error for data_copy:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Status\script2.py", line 59, in <module>
    view()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Status\script2.py", line 13, in view
    print(data_copy().da)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'da'
```

Comment: `data_copy()` doesn't return anything, and the objects don't have a `da` attribute. You can't access local variables as attributes.

Comment: `da` is a local variable in `data_copy()` and it is not accessible from outside of `data_copy()`. It is different with `window1` which is a class with a field `d`.

Comment: The name of the function is also misleading. It doesn't make a copy of anything.

Comment: Have you made da global?

Comment: @Linux4Life531, no da is a local variable.

Comment: I would make it global so it can be used outside the function

Comment: @Linux4Life531, even i make it as global.. the output will be empty list. The changes wont be affecting in the script2 (same as **window2.d**)

Comment: Try self.d instead of just d

Answer (score 0):

A common reason you have NoneType where you don't expect it is the assignment of an in-place operation on a mutable object. For example:

```
 mylist = mylist.sort()
```

The `sort()` method of a list sorts the list in-place, that is, `mylist` is modified. But the actual return value of the method is `None` and not the list sorted. So you've just assigned `None` to `mylist`. If you next try to do, say, `mylist.append(1)`,

Python will give you this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a function in the second script which takes your data as an argument and call it in the first script.

```py
from script2 import view


class Window2:
    def __init__(self, data):  # init should take self, it is an instance of class
        self.data = data


window_2 = Window2('some data')  # creating instance

view(window_2.data)  # call function from script2


# script2

def view(data):
    print(data)

# > 'some data'
```